# Laptop in a suitcase

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, electronic-items, san-francisco

When I go to airport, I recall following this procedure:

Go at the kiosks (? how do we call them?) and the service person from the airliner will make sure my ticket is OK and will ask for my suitcase, which I give it right there.

Then, when I am checked later on (you know where they ask you to take off your watch, belt, etc.), **they will ask about laptops, and if I have one, they will open the tray** and make sure it's a laptop.

**However, what about the case that the laptop is in the suitcase?**

I do not want *them* to freak out when they see it in there (don't worry about its safety). It will be accompanied by 2 chargers and 2 mouses.

---

<sub>If it matters, I will be traveling from San Francisco, to a destination in Europe, via transit in another European city.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with having a laptop or even a desktop computer in the suitcase. I did this just last week going through Atlanta. They did open the suitcase and left a note stating that, including a number to call and reference for the search. From the X-ray machine, what they probably see are some dark blocks and wires connecting them, so they will check it. They do the same for my tripod BTW, but by no means is a laptop prohibited. There are some restrictions on loose batteries but this does not apply to your situation. See [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-it-against-regulations-to-pack-my-laptop-battery-on-its-own-in-my-checked-lug/35673) question for details.

In my case, they even knew it was a computer since I declared it at the Check-In Counter (that is what you call kiosks) in order to buy insurance for it. See [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71813/does-insurance-for-expensive-items-in-checked-luggage-exist) question for details.

Checks are usually done at the departure airport but usually when entering Europe, they are done one more time at your point of entry into Europe. So you may get one or two notes regarding inspection. It would be good for you to have a copy of the invoice for the laptop in case you need to make a claim to insurance should something happen.

Comment: Check-In Counter, now I learnt something new, thanks! They did open it at the Check-In Counter?

Comment: @gsamaras *Check-In counter* is the place where they check tickets and passports. *Security check-point* is where they look at your stuff, pass it through x-ray and you through a metal detector or scanner. For insurance, they can decide to open it at the check-in counter too but usually, they don't.

Comment: Damn it Itai, sorry but I am still confused. I was referring to the place were we go to our airliner to give our suitcase. Then we move on, and pass through Check-In Counter and then Security Check. But the suitcase is given in the 1st stop (in the airliner's kiosks), so that it can go in the cargo.

Comment: @gsamaras - Depends on the airport. In some, you give the luggage at the *Check-in Counter* and, if you did your check-in online, you go to the *Baggage Drop* area. In others, you go to both the *Check-in Counter* and then the *Baggage Drop* area which is before the *Security Check-point* because you should only have your carry-on and personal item with you when passing security. The *Check-In* counter is before the *Baggage Drop* area because that is where they tag your luggage. For online checked baggage, which is not always possible, there is an automated kiosks which prints the labels.

Comment: I see, you got my upvote. So, do you know what is the case for San Francisco airport? I didn't booked my flight, someone else did for me, I bet they did it online. Moreover, I will do my check-in online.

Comment: @gsamaras This may have changed but IIRC - it's been a few years since passing through SF - you will have to go to the check-in counter because you have an international leg and they will check your passport there. They will also tag your luggage and tell you where you have to pick it up which may be your final destination or not, often if your last leg is domestic. In that case, you will have to move your luggage through customs.